# How to insert nodes into a Views result

Tags: views, hooks

In Drupal 7, I have a View that works great but I'd like to add a few nodes into the result arbitrarily outside of the scope of the View.

Basically, let's see the View returns Content Type X, I want to include a few nodes from Content Type Y that are in addition to whatever the View generates from Content Type X.

My preliminary thought was to use hook_views_pre_render but I'm not convinced that is the best solution....yet.

Comment: Add a filter of "content is of type", select X and Y on check list.

Comment: @NoSssweat The problem with that is I would get all of Content Type Y included.  I just want a subset of Content Type Y to be included with all of the results of Content Type X

Comment: can you draw a picture/diagram on how that would look like?

Comment: @NoSssweat I apologize for not being clearer.  Let's say I create a view for Content Type X and it returns 10 nodes.  I want to include 4 other nodes in the result that would not (and cannot) pass the filter for the original view.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Are these other Y nodes displayed, at the bottom, after the 10 nodes of X? Or are they mingled with the X nodes? PS: I am a visual person, a diagram or picture will def help.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [`hook_views_pre_execute`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_execute/7) (see [example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/152979/1908)) or [`hook_views_post_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_render/7) where you can add arbitrarily content (new rows or html code) into the view to fake the nodes.

Please check the following [code example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/149470/1908) to give you some idea.

You may also compare how other Views-based modules doing non-database query results, such as [Search API Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) or [YQL Views Query Backend](https://www.drupal.org/project/yql_views_query).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Views [Field View module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) can help with that, you can create a view for X content type, and embed a another view in it as a field that show Content type Y.

Comment: It looks like this will just tack on the additional view in the same way an Attachment would, right?

Comment: no this is different because you can dynamically load another view, or  you can pass arguments or use tokens.

Comment: Tried using the module but one problem: The view does not use fields, it displays teaser.  I tried sticking it in the View header or footer, but then it's outside the results.

Comment: This might help [Views node field](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewsnodefield). so you can use Fields and render your teaser as well.

Answer (score 0):

The module that works best for this in my experience is [Views Row Insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_row_insert).  Also available for modern Drupal (Drupal 8+).

Currently it supports blocks and custom text, so you would have to get your nodes as blocks first— this could be done easily with another view producing block displays.